# How to implement physical web using Eddystone Url beacon without app

Tags: beacon, eddystone-url

I have an Eddystone url beacon in which I have configured an https url.Now I want to broadcast that url in form of notification in google chrome but I am not able to do it.I have tried all methods of physical web but I am not able to receive any notification on my phone.Please let me know how to do that and the best possible solution.I don't want the user to install any app.Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the support of Physical Web (based on Eddystone URL) was dropped from Chrome without any official communication from Google. First from iOS and later also from Chrome. See [this issue](https://github.com/google/physical-web/issues/931).

The support for nearby notifications was also dropped. See [docs](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview).

Some information about discontinued support at [Estimote web site](https://developer.estimote.com/eddystone/physical-web/).

So there is no way to show notification without installing an application.

Comment: Is there any other way through which we can achieve this...other than beacons....!!

Comment: @AadharMathur QRcodes are unintrusive and now supported by Android and iOS without a 3rd party app, the other way is NFC through NDEF where you can open apps or URLs (some OS would block URLs via NDEF for obvious security reasons).